# Dependecy injection of arguments known at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I've been using IoC container's for quite some time but today I've found some "pattern" appearing in code over and over again. To give you some background I am now working on web application basically used for data analysis. There is a set of features there, that requires user to pick up what we call `QueryTypeContex` at the very beginning. Once this query type is chosen other steps may be taken but that all are performed in this specific `QueryTypeContex`. In the gui the `QueryTypeContex` pick up is represented as opening new tab with other controls.

When user is working with given `QueryTypeContex` all ajax calls to the server include `QueryTypeId` that identifies users choice and is used to build `QueryTypeContex` on the server which then is used for various data retrieval and manipulation.

What I've found is that many of our controllers (we use asp.net mvc) that are constructed with Ioc container have one thing in common. There is an action method that looks somewhat like this:

```
public class AttributeController : Controller 
{
  public AttributeController(IUsefulService usefulService)
  {
     _usefulservice = usefulService;
  }
  ActionResult GetAttributes(QueryTypeContex context)
  {
    var dataDto = _usefulService.Manipulate(context, currentUser);
    return JSon(dataDto);
  }
  ...
}
```

In order to bind `QueryTypeContex` to action argument we use custom model binder that pulls some information from database. Once the service gets `QueryTypeContex` as argument it passes it or its properties down to its collaborators in method arguments for instance data access layer. And so there is a factory class that looks like this

```
public interface IDateValueFactory 
{
   DateValue CurrentYear(QueryTypeContex context);
   DateValue RollingMonth(int numberOfMonths, QueryTypeContex context);
   DateValue RollingQuareter(int numberOfQuarters, QueryTypeContex context);
}

public class DateValueFactory : IDateValueFactory 
{
  public DateValueFactory(IDateValueDb dateValueDb)
  {
    _dateValueDb = dateValueDb;
  }

  public DateValue CurrentYear(QueryTypeContext context)
  {
    var currentYear = _dateValueDb.GetCurrentYear(context.Id);
    return new DateValue(DateValueType.CurrentYear, currentYear, context);
  }

  public DateValue RollingMonth(int numberOfMonths, QueryTypeContex context)
  {
    return new DateValue(DateValueType.RollingMonth, numberOfMonths, context);
  }
  ...

}
```

As you see all of these methods get `QueryTypeContex` as a parameter more importantly **they all get the very same instance of  `QueryTypeContex` during their short life** (one web request). So I started to wonder if I could refactor this so that whenever many service class methods require `QueryTypeContex` as arguments it would be injected via constructor instead of passing the same value over an over again. For example:

```
public interface IDateValueFactory 
{
   DateValue CurrentYear();
   DateValue RollingMonth(int numberOfMonths);
   DateValue RollingQuareter(int numberOfQuarters);
}

public class DateValueFactory : IDateValueFactory 
{
  public DateValueFactory(IDateValueDb dateValueDb, QueryTypeContext context)
  {
    _dateValueDb = dateValueDb;
    _context = context;
  }

  public DateValue CurrentYear()
  {
    var currentYear = _dateValueDb.GetCurrentYear(_context.Id);
    return new DateValue(DateValueType.CurrentYear, currentYear, _context);
  }

  public DateValue RollingMonth(int numberOfMonths)
  {
    return new DateValue(DateValueType.RollingMonth, numberOfMonths, _context);
  }
  ...

}
```

And now the real question:
**Is this a good idea to to this sort of thing or it violates some design principles i should adhere to ?**

In order to inject `QueryTypeContex` instance, builded using information from http request I thought about embedding the QueryTypeId in the uris so it would be available in the RouteData on the server. Then before the controller is constructed I could pull it out, build the `QueryTypeContex`, create nested IoC container for that request and inject it into the container. Then whenever some class would need `QueryTypeContex` to perform its job it would simply declare it as constructor argument.

Comment: Have you read the guide?

Comment: @PhoenixFF which guide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you can meaningfully push to the constructor as dependencies, you should. Dependencies wired up with constructor injection are **implementation details**, whereas method parameters are part of your **model's API**.

It's much easier to refactor dependencies wired through constructors than to change an API, so for maintainability reasons you should prefer as few method parameters as possible.

Comment: Hmm, in this case, based on the example given, I would likely keep the context-passing in the method.  Otherwise the implementation is making an assumption about how it's configured (i.e. it's lifecycle).  Also, how would the context be provided to the constructor through the container, via some kind of BuildUp method?  It seems like an abstract factory, with the context passed into the Create() method would make more sense?  (to be clear: I'm not arguing with your answer, as I am struggling with this issue myself).